# in Meteor+React, how can i render a child React component in a parent React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, meteor-blaze

i have defined a Parent component and a Child component. i'm getting an error when i associate them.

**Parent.jsx**

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import {Child} from '/imports/ui/components/Child';

export default class Parent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Child />
        );
    }
}
```

**Child.jsx**

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';

export default class Child extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>child</div>
        );
    }
}
```

i have registered the parent with Blaze:

```
Template.registerHelper("Parent", function() {
    return Parent;
});
```

... and i'm using it like this:

```
<div>
    {{> React component=Parent }}
</div>
```

i'm getting this error in the browser console:

> Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined,
>   boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a
>   ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of
>   `Parent`.

i do have other React components working in this project, but none of them have this simple parent/child relationship. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you need to register the child component too

Comment: Maybe you should `export Child` instead of `export default Child` or `import Child` instead of `import {Child}`.

Comment: @caisah aggggh yes that was it. forgot my module import/export rules, nothing to do w/ React. if you put your comment as an answer, i can accept it.

Comment: @JDHrnnts, no need to register the child one, only the ones used by Blaze.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should

`export Child` instead of `export default Child`

or

`import Child` instead of `import {Child}`